# Putting Node.js/Socket.io Onto a Website

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io

So I'm getting into working with node.js and socket.io to make real-time web games, but I'm running into some obstacles.

I've already figured out how to install node.js and socket.io on my computer, and I can run basic servers and open them through `http://localhost:8888/`.

But now what I don't understand, and there doesn't seem to be anything on the web that explains this, is how to get this onto a website. Obviously, someone else on the internet that enters that same URL isn't going to see the same thing as what's on my screen. How do I get this onto a webpage so that anyone that visits that URL accesses the server?

I tried opening the port and then using `http://<my external IP>:8888` but that doesn't work. Some sources seem to say that I need to install something on the website, but I installed node.js on my computer through command prompt, so I don't understand how that would work on a website. I found instructions for Linux, but I'm running Windows.

Comment: This is not a Node.js / Socket.io question. This is about basic knowledge of web hosting / addresses / network, etc. that should be addressed and / or learned somewhere else. Here are a few tips: [let's learn basics](http://www.webhostingsecretrevealed.net/web-hosting-beginner-guide/)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a:

- **web server** - to host your game. You can, for instance, rent an [EC2 instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) from Amazon and install there all software required (Node.js, database, ...) or go with PaaS (Platform as a Service) solution like [Nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/) or [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) where you'll be given Node.js out of the box.
- **domain** - to register a human-readable name for your web serwer (like. www.my-game.com). Normally, once you get your server, it'll have some IP address assigned to it. Domain name is an alias for it, easier to type and remember. Similar to, as in your case, `localhost` is just an alias for an IP `127.0.0.1` (special address meaning local system).

Of course, another solution would be to host app on your local PC and set up your router to forward traffic from it's external IP to your PC (assuming your ISP assigned you public IP). But then you'll have to worry about your PC, router and internet link being always online. And it'd be way slower than when going with external, dedicated hosting.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. What would the code look like? I already have access to almost all of the resources you've mentioned, but I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: then be more precise on your problem. What does not work? Do you get the website or do you not get the web socket connection? Have you opened the server firewall?

Comment: This answer is correct. You don't have to install anything on the website because it doesn't make sense. I've installed node.js on server PC running Windows server 2008 and specified a port on which node.js runs. You also need to do the same if you don't want to serve it on Heroku etc...

Comment: I apologize, but in general I just have no idea what to do at all, which is why my question can't be more precise, as I have no idea what I'm even supposed to ask. Using my external IP doesn't work, which I've mentioned. Those things you've mentioned, like Nodejitsu, how would I use these things? What are the steps I need to take? How do I need to change up my code?

Comment: @user3395644 - if you want to try Nodejitsu out, maybe follow [this tutorial](https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/quickstart/)? It'll show you how to run code on their infrastructure.